# IBM Text to Speech: How to have correct pronounciation of English words in German text?

Tags: ibm-cloud, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I am using the [IBM Text to Speech](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/index.html) to process some German texts. Pronounciation of the text with a German voice is working ok. However, the text contains some English words and phrases. For those, the pronounciation sometimes is incorrect. How can I fix that?

Example:
`Er kommt aus Amerika und nennt sich TJ.`

`TJ` should be pronounced like someone from California would do.

Comment: Just FYI, one of the IBM people requested the [ibm-text-to-speech] tag be burninated in [this meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355479/remove-tag-ibm-text-to-speech)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make it work by using [Speech Synthesis Markup Language (SSML)](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/SSML.html) on my text. The German text remains the same. For the English expressions I provided some "phonemes". Here is the one for `TJ`:

```
<phoneme alphabet="ibm" ph="tIZE">TJ</phoneme>
```

I had to use [German symbols](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/text-to-speech/SPRs.html#deSymbols) which can be found in the docs.